# How and Why the last 8 bytes MUST be overwritten in TLS 1.3 as described below if negotiating TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.1?

Tags: random, https, tls1.3

In RFC 8446. About the random in ServerHello send by Server.

In 4.1.3.  Server Hello

> 32 bytes generated by a secure random number generator.  See Appendix C for additional information.  The last 8 bytes MUST be overwritten as described below if negotiating TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.1, but the remaining bytes MUST be random.  This structure is generated by the server and MUST be generated independently of the ClientHello.random.

Why and How ?

> The last 8 bytes MUST be overwritten as described below if negotiating TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.1

Answer (score 0):

In RFC 8446

4.1.3.  Server Hello

> TLS 1.3 has a downgrade protection mechanism embedded in the server's
>      random value.  TLS 1.3 servers which negotiate TLS 1.2 or below in
>      response to a ClientHello MUST set the last 8 bytes of their Random
>      value specially in their ServerHello.
>
> If negotiating TLS 1.2, TLS 1.3 servers MUST set the last 8 bytes of
>   their Random value to the bytes:

```
 44 4F 57 4E 47 52 44 01
```

> If negotiating TLS 1.1 or below, TLS 1.3 servers MUST, and TLS 1.2
>      servers SHOULD, set the last 8 bytes of their ServerHello.Random
>      value to the bytes:

```
 44 4F 57 4E 47 52 44 00
```